# Is it possible to avoid preflight requests when you use custom request headers?

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

Is it possible to avoid preflight requests when you use custom request headers?
I've gone through the following URL : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests
But when custom headers are used, preflight requests are enabled.

Is there a way to avoid it?